# Adding Z-dimension point to layer

Tags: python, pyqgis, point, z-value, qgsvectorlayer

I have a point. I want to add to a Point layer in QGIS 3.16, but I can't get the Z-dimension working on my layer. The point is created but has no z-value...

```py
coord = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer().crs().authid()
r_layer = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs=" + coord, "MyPoints", "memory")
r_layer.setProviderEncoding(u'UTF-8')
pr = r_layer.dataProvider()
#CODE that handles fields#

zPoint = QgsPoint(55, 34, -2)
seg.setGeometry(QgsGeometry(zPoint))
pr.addFeatures([seg])
r_layer.updateExtents()
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(r_layer)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing

```
"Point?crs="
```

with:

```
"PointZ?crs="
```

Comment: Thanks alot, Working perfectly